# Python working with circular references

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, module, pycharm, circular-reference

I have trouble with circular references. Sometime it's work sometime not. i am brand new in programming and it's something here that i don't understand.

Take a look at this code.

module gui:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
import task as task
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Window(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Avoid C R")

        self.main_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL,
                                spacing=10)

        self.question = Gtk.Label("what is your name ?")
        self.answer = Gtk.Entry()
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Use fonction in another module")

        self.add(self.main_box)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.question, True,True, 0)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.answer, True, True, 0)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)

        self.button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self, widget):
        task.print_name()

win = Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

module task:

```
import gui as gui


def print_name():
    x = gui.win.answer.get_text()
    print("Name is ", x)
```

i already have a 10 000 lines code whit this pattern and it's working well. i use it every day.

But now i try to rewrite my code with this same pattern and it don't work anymore. I am pretty sure that is a question of circular references.

My question is « If i have pretty big application and i want to use many modules : what is the right way to avoid circular references ? »

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the window to `print_name`. Now you can remove the module reference and it can be used by many programs to boot.

task.py:

```
def print_name(gui):
    x = gui.win.answer.get_text()
    print("Name is ", x)
```

Comment: That's the way. I will have to act for all of my future development ?

Comment: Likely, yes., and it may be worth refactoring existing code. An alternate pattern is to have `task.py` be a subclass of `Window` and have it be the script that starts the gui. I don't know enough of your system to say for sure what's better in any given case.